# npm prebuild : how to fail build if prebuild has an error

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I'm using a "prebuild" hook to run some logic before the actual "build" is called. Is there anyway to make the build fail in case the prebuild logic has detected an error?

I've tried:

```
process.exit( -1 );
```

into the prebuild Node JS script and:

```
throw err;
```

with no success.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Let's say I have _prebuild.js_ with it's content as `console.log("prebuilding"); process.exit(-1);`, and in the `scripts` section of _package.json_ I have `"scripts": { "prebuild": "node prebuild.js", "build": "echo \"building\"" }`. When I run `$ npm run build` the words _"prebuilding"_ do get printed to the console, followed by npm errors, i.e. the words _"building"_ never get printed to the console. I suggest you provide further specific details about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating a bit more after RobC comment and replying here to help other people having the same issue.

This is related to the usage of cross-var:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "cross-var $INIT_CWD/my-path/my-script",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  },
```

Looking at the source code of cross-var I've noticed two different paths of execution depending on whether the executed script has some parameters or not; in that case spawn() instead of exec() is being used. And it seems to better handle execution on error. So I end up writing something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "cross-var $INIT_CWD/my-path/my-script hack",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  },
```

Now, a failing prebuild is properly stopping the build process.

Thanks RobC for your comment.